# Android manifest file with properties from other property file

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-maps-android-api-2

In general android manifest for my app that uses google map v2 looks something like this:

```xml
<manifest>
   ...       
   <application>
      ...
      <!-- Google API Key -->
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="XYZ...ZYX" />
      ...
   </application>
<manifest>
```

The question is, if it's possible to do something like this:

```xml
<manifest>
   ...       
   <application>
      ...
      <!-- Google API Key -->
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@{my.google.api.key}" />
      ...
   </application>
<manifest>
```

and have `my_local.property` file in my project with line:
`my.google.api.key=XYZ...ZYX` ?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can use [manifest placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) to achieve what you needed to, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string resources for this and manifest would be

```
android:value="@string/google_api_key"
```

Comment: Yes, I also figure it out like this, but string resource is not (in my opinion) a good place to hide there a configuration property. What's more I would like to add this my_local.property file to ignore for my version control system and keep string resource file in it

Comment: You could create several string xml files and one of them can contain only the key, you could ignore that file in VCS. Another way is to use ant to generate properly manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the recommended way for using `local.properties` file to hide your API keys from `AndroidManifest.xml` file and other parts of the project is this: [Secrets Gradle plugin](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/secrets-gradle-plugin).